# Using mutate() on groups which have been arranged - Will not cumsum() each group accurately

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, cumsum

Working in R. I have a large dataset of trees that are organized by stand and plots within a stand. I need to organize the trees in each plot by size (DBH) in descending order, and then find the `cumsum()` of the basal area (cross sectional area) in each plot. The point is to have the cumulative sum of the basal areas of all of the larger trees in a plot.

When I run the group by and arrange and print out the tibble it is arranged correctly, but once I try to run mutate on it I have no idea what is going on under the hood, as the values calculated seem completely random.

The function should create groups by plots within a stand, order them in desc order by DBH in each stand, and then find the `cumsum(BA)` within each plot minus its own BA `cumsum(BA)-BA` . Why does this malfunction when I get to the `mutate()` portion of the script! It has been driving me nuts. I tried a few things in base R and also couldn't sort it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. This seems like it should be easy and not driving me up at a wall!

```
BA.Larger.Trees <- function(Stand, Plot, Tree, DBH, BA) {
  Temp <- tibble(Stand, Plot, Tree, DBH, BA)
  Temp <- Temp %>%
    group_by(Plot, Stand) %>%
    arrange(desc(DBH), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(
      X = (cumsum(BA) - BA))
    )
  return(Temp$X)
  }
```

Here is some sample data:

```
Stand <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Plot  <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
Tree  <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
DBH   <- c(4, 12, 6, 11, 12, 6, 1, 3, 2, 12, 16, 13)
BA    <- c(.04, .12, .06, .11, .12, .06, .01, .03, .02, .12, .16, .13)
```

Comment: The expected output is a variable BAL which gives the basal area of all of the larger trees in a plot. The goal is to identify the smallest trees in each plot to predict mortality. The output would look someone like 'BA <- c(0, .12, .18, 0, .12, .23, 0, .03, .05, 0, .16, .29)`

Comment: How do you perform the calculation? How the 2nd value is 0.12 and 3rd value is 0.18? What output do you get? Do you have `plyr` loaded in your environment in which case use `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: It is the cumulative sum of the BA minus the BA of the individual tree for each unique plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass tibble in the function instead of passing individual vectors. Try :

```
library(dplyr)

BA.Larger.Trees <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    arrange(Stand, Plot, desc(BA)) %>%
    group_by(Stand, Plot) %>%
    mutate(X = cumsum(BA) - BA)
}

Temp <- tibble(Stand, Plot, Tree, DBH, BA)
result <- BA.Larger.Trees(Temp)
result$X
#[1] 0.00 0.12 0.18 0.00 0.12 0.23 0.00 0.03 0.05 0.00 0.16 0.29
```